# В чем суть ковариантности и контравариантности делегатов?

Tags: c#, c#-faq, делегаты

Изучаю по книге работу с делегатами и есть там пример, объясняющий, что такое ковариантность и контравариантность. Решил подробнее поискать в гугле, но объяснений так и не нашел.
В книге сказано, что ковариантность позволяет присвоить делегату метод, возвращаемым типом которого служит класс, производный от класса, указываемого в возвращаемом типе делегата. А контравариантность позволяет присвоить делегату метод, типом параметра которого служит класс, являющийся базовым для класса, указываемого в объявлении делегата.
К сожалению в практике это так разобрать и не смог, может кто сможет разжевать данный пример подробнее или преподнести свой, более легкий?

```
class X
{
    public int Val;
}

class Y : X { }

//Этот делегат возвращает объект класса X и принимает объект класса Y в качестве аргумента
delegate X ChangeIt(Y obj);

class CoContraVariance
{
    //Этот метод возвращает объект класса X и имеет объект класса X в качестве параметра
    static X IncrA(X obj)
    {
        X temp = new X();
        temp.Val = obj.Val + 1;
        return temp;
    }

    //Этот метод возвращает объект класса Y и имеет объект класса Y в качестве параметра
    static Y IncrB(Y obj)
    {
        Y temp = new Y();
        temp.Val = obj.Val + 1;
        return temp;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Y Yob = new Y();

        ChangeIt change = IncrA;
        X Xob = change(Yob);

        Console.WriteLine("Xob: {0}", Xob.Val);

        change = IncrB;
        Yob = (Y)change(Yob);

        Console.WriteLine("Yob: {0}", Yob.Val);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Наверное лучше объяснение: [Difference between Covariance & Contra-variance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance)

Comment: А что, собственно, в этом примере непонятно?

Comment: В вашем вопросе не содержится собственно вопроса.  Что вы подразумеваете по "разжевать данный пример"? Вдумчиво и медленно прочитать, по словам, повторить текстовку из книги? Или построчно прокомментировать пример (он же и так прокомментирован достаточно детально)?

Comment: Непонятно как устроены ковариантность и контравариантность. В примере показано, что делегат может получить ссылку на два метода, с разными входными и выходными параметрами. Здесь ковариантность это ChangeIt change = IncrB;, а контравариантностью ChangeIt change = IncrA;? В общем, не понятно определение ковариантности и контравариантности, слишком уж они запутанные.

Comment: Проверьте, правильно ли я понял in и out в делегатах. Я понял это вот так - in разрешает принять вместо базового, еще и производный. out разрешает вернуть вместо базового также и производный.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Для начала, давайте глянем, что такое эта самая вариантность.

Пусть у нас есть два класса, `Car` и `BMW`. Очевидно, что `BMW` есть подкласс `Car`: каждая бэха является машиной.

Обычно при этом говорят так: «везде, где вы используете `Car`, можно использовать и `BMW`». Это на самом деле почти правда, но не совсем.

Пример: если у вас есть список машин, вы не можете вместо него использовать список BMW. Почему? А вот почему. Пускай вас есть `List<BMW>`, и вы используете его как список машин. Тогда, раз это список *машин*, в него можно добавить и <s>Запорожец</s> Lanos, правильно? Вот тут-то и начинаются проблемы. Если у вас в коде написано:

```
List<BMW> bmws = new List<BMW>();
List<Car> cars = bmws;   // поскольку список БМВ - это список машин
cars.Add(new Lanos());
BMW bmw = bmvs[0];       // ой.
```

Внимательно посмотрите на этот код и подумайте над ним: он иллюстрирует проблему. (И он не откомпилируется: язык C# спроектирован так, чтобы не приводить к проблемам.) Проблема с *записью* в список. Если мы в список добавим произвольную машину, будет очень плохо: мы сможем нарушить гарантии, которые даёт нам система типов!

Если бы у нас был список, доступный *только на чтение*, то проблем бы как раз не было:

```
IEnumerable<BMW> bmws = new List<BMW>() { new BMW() };
IEnumerable<Car> cars = bmws;   // а так можно
//cars.Add(new Lanos());    // <-- не скомпилируется
```

Итак, что у нас получается? Несмотря на то, что BMW — машина, *список* BMW уже не обязательно является списком машин. А вот список BMW, доступный лишь на чтение, таки является списком машин.

Есть?

Теперь назад к вариантности. Мы говорим о ковариантности в общем смысле, если что-то меняется *аналогичным* образом. В случае наследования классов: мы можем вместо `Car` использовать `BMW`, и *точно так же* мы можем вместо `IEnumerable<Car>` использовать `IEnumerable<BMW>`.

---

Окей, это было длинное вступление, теперь вернёмся к теме: ковариантность делегатов. Пусть у нас есть делегат, зависящий от типа `Car`. Поменяем в его определении `Car` на `BMW`, можно ли новый делегат использовать вместо старого?

Давайте рассуждать логически. Если у нас есть такой делегат:

```
public delegate Car Replace(Car original);
```

(он принимает на вход `Car`, и выдаёт другой экземпляр `Car`), то можно ли вместо него подставить функцию, описывающуюся делегатом такого вида:

```
public BMW MyReplace(BMW original) { ... }
```

? Разумеется, нет, потому что делегат может принимать на вход любую машину, а наша функция хочет только BMW. Так что здесь ковариантности нету: такую функцию нельзя использовать там, где требуется данный делегат.

А вот если наш вариантный тип данных (то есть, `Car`) находится лишь в позиции возвращаемого типа:

```
public delegate Car Create();
```

то на его месте можно использовать функцию такого вида:

```
public BMW CreateBmw() { ... }
```

(если подходила любая машина, то BMW тоже подойдёт).

Это и есть ковариантность делегатов: там, где от вас в коде требуется делегат, вы можете вместо него предоставить ковариантный делегат.

Пример кода, использующий это:

```
// это функция, принимающая делегат:
Car PrepareCar(Create carCreator)
{
    Car car = carCreator();
    car.ManufacturingDate = DateTime.Now;
    car.Mileage = 0;
    return car;
}

// это функция, которая ковариантна Create: она возвращает не Car, а BMW
BMW BmwFactory()
{
    var bmw = new BMW();
    bmw.EnginePower = 400;
    return bmw;
}

// вы можете использовать эту функцию как аргумент PrepareCar
// хотя её сигнатура другая:
return PrepareCar(BmwFactory);
```

---

Контравариантность работает в другую сторону: там вы можете использовать делегат, работающий с *базовым* типом там, где ожидается делегат с производным типом. Такое работает для аргументов функций:

```
delegate double BmwTester(BMW bmw);

void TestAndPublish(BmwTester tester)
{
    var bmw = new BMW();
    double testResult = tester(bmw);
    PublishResult(testResult);
}

double UniversalTester(Car car)
{
    return 5.0;
}

// вы можете использовать UniversalTester, хотя у него и не совсем подходящая сигнатура
TestAndPublish(UniversalTester);
```

Это работает по тем же причинам, что и ковариантность: если тестеру подходит любой тип машины, то он сможет работать и с BMW тоже.

Comment: `Create1` тут `Car PrepareCar(Create1 carCreator)`  тоже опечатка?

Comment: @Grundy: Остатки от старой редакции ответа :) Спасибо, сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 17):

Каждый из параметров-типов обобщенного делегата или интерфейса должен быть помечен как ковариантный или контравариантный. Это не приводит ни к каким нежелательным последствиям, но позволит применять ваших делегатов в большем количестве сценариев и позволит вам осуществлять приведение типа переменной обобщенного делегата к тому же типу делегата с другим параметром-типом.

Параметры-типы могут быть:

- **Инвариантными**. Параметр-тип не может изменяться.
- **Контравариантными**. Параметр-тип может быть преобразован от класса к
  классу, производному от него. В языке C# контравариантный тип
  обозначается ключевым словом **in**. Контравариантный параметр-тип
  может появляться только во входной позиции, например, в качестве
  аргументов метода.
- **Ковариантными**. Аргумент-тип может быть преобразован от класса к
  одному из его базовых классов. В языке С# ковариантный тип
  обозначается ключевым словом **out**. Ковариантный параметр обобщенного
  типа может появляться только в выходной позиции, например, в качестве
  возвращаемого значения метода.

---

Предположим, что существует следующий тип делегата:

```
public delegate TResult MyDelegate<in T, out TResult>(T arg);
```

Здесь параметр-тип `T` помечен словом **in**, делающим его контравариантным, а параметр-тип `TResult` помечен словом **out**, делающим его ковариантным. Пусть объявлена следующая переменная:

```
MyDelegate<Object, ArgumentException> fn1 = null;
```

Ее можно привести к типу `MyDelegate` с другими параметрами-типами:

```
MyDelegate<String, Exception> fn2 = fn1; // Явного приведения типа не требуется 
Exception e = fn2("");
```

Это говорит о том, что `fn1` ссылается на функцию, которая получает `Object` и возвращает `ArgumentException`. Переменная `fn2` пытается сослаться на метод, который получает `String` и возвращает `Exception`. Так как мы можем передать `String` методу, которому требуется тип `Object` (тип `String` является производным от `Object`), а результат метода, возвращающего `ArgumentException`, может интерпретироваться как `Exception` (тип `ArgumentException` является производным от `Exception`), представленный здесь программный код откомпилируется, а **на этапе компиляции будет сохранена безопасность типов**.

---

**Примечание**
Вариантность действует только в том случае, если компилятор сможет установить  возможность преобразования ссылок между типами. Другими словами, вариантность неприменима для значимых типов из-за необходимости упаковки (boxing).

Answer (score 1):

Как выводы:

Ковариантность (**`out`**): 
В производном типе по определению будут доступны члены базового типа. Поэтому, если функция возвращает производный тип, вызывающий код через него всё равно получит доступ к членам базового типа.

Контравариантность (**`in`**):
В производном типе по определению будут доступны члены базового типа. Поэтому, если функция принимает в своем аргументе производный тип, внутри себя через него она всё равно получит доступ к членам базового тип.