# Не выходит правильно наследовать интерфейс C#

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Есть интерфейс IHost

```
public interface IHost<TAddress, TPingResult> 
         where TAddress : IAddress 
         where TPingResult : IPingResult
{
    TAddress HostAddress { get; set; }
    TPingResult Response { get; set; }
    void SendRequest();
}
```

Затем его наследует ITCPHost

```
public interface ITCPHost: IHost<ITCPAddress, ITCPPingResult> 
{

}
```

И я реализую интерфейс ITCPHost в классе TCPHost

```
public class TCPHost : ITCPHost
{
    public ITCPAddress HostAddress { get; set; }
    public ITCPPingResult Response { get; set; }
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }

    public TCPHost(IPingResult response, IAddress address)
    {
        Response = (ITCPPingResult) response;
        HostAddress = (ITCPAddress) address;
    }

    public void SendRequest()
    {
        Метод что-то делает, не важно что...
    }
```

Затем я использую этот класс:

```
private static readonly Pinger.Pinger Pinger = new Pinger.Pinger();
private static readonly TCPPingResult Result = new TCPPingResult();
private static readonly TCPAddress Address = new TCPAddress("8.8.8.8",80);
private static readonly TCPHost Host = new TCPHost(Result, Address);
public PingHost()
{
    Pinger.PingEvent += NewPingHandler;
    Pinger.Ping(Host, 1); /* === ОШИБКА === */
}
```

В предпоследней строке кода выдает ошибку

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ProtocolPinger.Hosts.TCPHost' to 'ProtocolPinger.Hosts.IHost'  ProtocolPinger  D:\Projects\Visual Studio\ProtocolPinger\ProtocolPinger\Program.cs  27  Active

Почему он не принимает наследника интерфейса? В чем ошибка?

Сигнатура метода Ping:

```
public void Ping(IHost<IAddress, IPingResult> host, int period)
```

Comment: стоит добавить определения всех классов задействованных в коде. Как минимум _Pinger.Pinger_

Comment: не нравятся ему скорее generic-параметры, когда вместо `IAddress` имеем `ITCPAddress`

Comment: @Grundy дак сигнатура метода `ping` приведена, на кой весь класс то нужен?

Comment: вот тут может помочь: [В чем суть ковариантности и контравариантности делегатов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516687/186999)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Все дело в том, что `IHost<ITCPAddress, ITCPPingResult>` и `IHost<IAddress, IPingResult>` - это **разные** интерфейсы.

Для того, чтобы первый можно было скастовать ко второму - надо сделать его ковариантным: `interface IHost<out TAddress, out TPingResult>`. Но в таком случае типы-параметры можно будет использовать только в качестве выходных (на что и намекает ключевое слово out):

```
public interface IHost<out TAddress, out TPingResult> 
         where TAddress : IAddress 
         where TPingResult : IPingResult
{
    TAddress HostAddress { get; }
    TPingResult Response { get; }
    void SendRequest();
}
```

Если же вам нужны именно входные параметры, то задача решения не имеет, потому что `IAddress` невозможно привести к `ITCPAddress` в общем случае.