# Приведение универсальных типов <T>

Tags: c#

Есть задача:

```
public class A { }

public class A1 : A { }

public class A2 : A { }

public class B<T> where T : A { }

public class B1 : B<A1> { }

public class B2 : B<A2> { }

public class Conteiner<T, U> where T : B<U> where U : A
{ 
    T[] list;

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return list[index]; }
        set { list[index] = value; }
    }

    public void Set<K, N, M>(K conteiner)
        where K : Conteiner<N, M>
        where N : B<M>
        where M : A
    { 
        list[0] = conteiner[0]; <------Ошибка не удается преобразовать тип N в T.
    } 
}
```

Как решить или обойти проблему?

Comment: Переопределить `Set`: `public void Set(Conteiner<T, U> conteiner)`. Иначе это просто невозможно, так как у вас может быть `U=A1`, а `M=A2` и эти типы не приводятся

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В чем суть ковариантности и контравариантности делегатов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516687/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: В чем смысл делать ```Conteiner<T, U>``` и потом писать туда ```Conteiner<N, M>```. Какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: Мне нужно было создать классы(Conteiner и его наследники) хранящие списки классов наследуемых от A. Нужно по тому что каждый наследник хранит определенные данные, а контейнеры нужны для их внесения и изъятия. Данный код необходим для того что бы быстро преобразовать данные.

Answer (score 1):

можно обойтись делая так:

```
public class Conteiner<T, U> where T : B<U> where U : A
{
    T[] list;

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return list[index]; }
        set { list[index] = value; }
    }

    public void Set<K,N,M>(Conteiner<T, U> conteiner)
        where K : Conteiner<N, M>
        where N : B<M>
        where M : A
    {
        list[0] = conteiner[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Тогда и `<K,N,M>` не нужны, не так ли?