# Приведение обобщенных типов

Tags: c#

Есть задача приведения типов.

```
    class A{} 
    class A1:A{} 
    class A2:A1{} 

    class B<T> where T:A{} 
    class B1<T>:B<T> where T:A1{} 
    class B2:B1<A2>{} 

B2-->B1<A1>
```

Возникает ошибка приведения типов. Как реализовать приведение типов?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Приведение универсальных типов <T>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715399/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2-t)

Comment: Не стоит многократно задавать один и тот же вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Никак. Представьте, что в B1 у вас реализован вот так:

```
class B1<T> : B<T> where T : A1
{
    public T Some;
}
```

И где-то есть код, который, встретив результат вашей конвертации `B2-->B1<A1>` в виде `B1<A1> b1` делает:

```
b1.Some = new A1();
```

А ведь `b1` - это объект типа `B2`, и `b1.Some` - это на самом деле поле типа `A2`.

Компилятор не может проанализировать реализацию какого-то стороннего, по отношению к коду `B2-->B1<A1>`, класса. Компилятор не может предугадать, что дальше с результатом конвертации произойдет. Так что он просто запрещает саму конвертацию.

---

При этом проблема возникает только из-за наличия какой-то внутренней реализации класса B1, невидимой для компилятора в момент прохода по коду конвертации. Если использовать вместо класса `B1` интерфейс - то проблема легко решается добавлением модификаторов [`in`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-generic-modifier) / [`out`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier).

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите.

У нас известно, что  `B2` является (в смысле «*is a*», подтип) `B1<A2>`. Но `B1<A2>` не является `B1<A1>` несмотря на то, что `A2` является `A1`.

Почему так? Давайте рассмотрим на конкретном примере. Допустим, у нас есть `List<A2>`, почему его нельзя закастить в `List<A1>`, хотя `A2` можно закастить в `A1`? Потому что иначе было бы возможно вот что:

```
List<A2> good = new List<A2>();
List<A1> evil = (List<A1>)good;
evil.Add(new A1());  // катастрофа!
A2 a2 = good[0];     // в списке оказался A1!
```

По этой причине компилятор запрещает преобразование из `List<A2>` в `List<A1>`. Ну и по той же причине — из `B1<A2>` в `B1<A1>`.