# Task<TResult>. Ошибка инициализации

Tags: c#, task

```
Func<int, string> func = (int p) =>
{
  return p.ToString();
};
Task<string> task = new Task<string>(func, 7);
```

Ошибка  1   Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>.Task(System.Func<string>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)` имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов

Ошибка  2   Аргумент "1": преобразование типа из `System.Func<int,string>` в `System.Func<string>` невозможно

Ошибка  3   Аргумент "2": преобразование типа из `int` в `System.Threading.CancellationToken` невозможно

Как передать в функцию задания строго типизированный входной параметр типа int?

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать-то?

Comment: Ну, у задачи и правда нет конструктора который принимает указанные вами параметры...

Comment: Попробуйте выбрать конструктор из [вот этого списка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Если изменить тип входного параметра с int на object или dynemic, то все работает, но при этом такого конструктора нет.

Comment: Как это нет: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321565(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: т.е. вместо Func<int, string> func = (int p) =>... написать Func<object, string> func = (object p) =>

Comment: Можно так, но на самом деле это не очень хорошо - будет упаковка, лучше с помощью замыкания преобразуйте вашу функцию, принимающую параметр в функцию без параметра

Comment: Чтобы на ваш вопрос можно было ответить, отредактируйте его и напишите что вы хотите в итоге получить. Вы хотите запустить `func` с параметром `7`? Или что?

Comment: Для меня странно что конструктор public Task(Func<object, TResult> function,object state) не может автоматически упаковать входной аргумент (в данном случае int) в object

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что компилятор выбирает именно эту перегрузку? Если бы это было так, то ваш код бы работал. Но так как нет однозначности, он выбирает перегрузку с `CancellationToken` (почему - это уже другой вопрос)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Состряпаем из вашей функции, принимающей один параметр, функцию без параметров:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<int, string> func = (int p) =>
    {
        return p.ToString();
    };
    Task<string> task = new Task<string>(() => func(7));
    task.Start();
    string r = await task;
    Console.WriteLine(r);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Т.е. мы здесь определяем еще одну функцию (анонимную), это примерно тоже самое, что написать так:

```
Func<string> func2 = () => func(7);
Task<string> task = new Task<string>(func2);
```

Comment: да, спасибо, именно так я и сделал с подсказки, Yami

Answer (score 1):

Перегрузка с функцией и состоянием имеет [следующий вид](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd321565(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Task<TResult>(Func<Object, TResult>, Object)
```

Проблема в том, что в `Func<Object, TResult>` нельзя передать `Func<int, string>`.( Подробнее можно посмотреть в вопросе: [В чем суть ковариантности и контравариантности делегатов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516928/186999))

Для решения достаточно просто изменить тип делегата, на `Func<Object, TResult>`

```
Func<object, string> func = (object p) =>
{
  return p.ToString();
};
Task<string> task = new Task<string>(func, 7);
```

Comment: Упаковка же будет, хотя, наверное, по сравнению с накладными расходами на создание задачи, это пустяки

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я на самом деле просто не увидел строчку в вопросе: _Как передать в функцию задания **строго типизированный входной параметр** типа int?_ И ответил скорее: почему ошибка.