# C# Ковариантность и контравариантность

Tags: c#, наследование, интерфейс

Сущесвует два интерфейса:

```
public interface Test<out T>
{
 T action(int i);
 void step(T i); //ошибка
}

public interface Test_2<in T>
{
T action(int i);//ошибка
void step(T i); 
}
```

Я так понимаю Ковариантность и контравариантность накладывают на входные и выходные параметры некие ограничения. Почему?
P.S И зачем вообще нужно иногда дочерний клас приводить к родительскому либо родительский к дочернему? Примеры приветствуются.

Comment: На сайте есть поиск, ваш вопрос скорее всего закроют за повтор. [Вот достаточно подробный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516928/222542).

Comment: @Bulson за ссылку на вопрос - спасибо. Но все же это не единственый вопрос, другой вопрос на счёт приведения типов

Comment: Читайте ответ, на который я дал ссылку. Там все есть. Или подправьте свой вопрос, что конкретно вам не понятно.