# C# список generics

Tags: c#, generics

помогите пожалуйста разобраться с Generics.

Есть классы:

```
public class DataBase  {}

public class DataA:DataBase{}

public class DataB : DataBase{}

.....

public abstract class Comand<T> where T:DataBase
{
    public abstract void DoStuff(T p)
    {      
    }

    public virtual void DoOtherStuff()
    {    
    }
}

public class ComandA:Comand<DataA>
{
    public override void DoStuff(DataA p) //(DataA p)
    {

    }
}

public class ComandB : Comand<DataB>
{
    public override void DoStuff(DataB p)  
    {
    }
}
```

Далее в классе, который собирается работать со списками команд я бы хотел сделать так, как указано в комментариях, т.е. общий список для всех команд, но могу только явно указать тип списков. Возможно ли такое, если да, то как этого добиться, если нет, то почему?

```
public class Program
{
        List<ComandA> comandsA=new List<ComandA>();
        List<ComandB> comandsB=new List<ComandB>();

//List<Comand<???>> comands=new List<Comand<???>>(); не могу так сделать

void CreateComands()
    {
        ComandA comandA=new ComandA();
        ComandB comandB = new ComandB();

        comandsA.Add(comandA);
        comandsB.Add(comandB);

        //comands.Add(comandA);   не могу так сделать
        //comands.Add(comandB);   не могу так сделать

    }
}
```

Comment: так надо список класса Command тогда: List<Comand<T>> comandsA=new List<Comand<T>>();

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516687/218063