# Контравариантность в универсальных интерфейсах. C#

Tags: c#, .net

На англоязычном сайте меня заминусовали и закидали ссылками на темы, которые и вызывают вопросы.
Изучаю программирование. Реально хочется понять.

Итак. Я пытаюсь понять какие конкретные прикладные задачи я **не смогу решить без контравариантности**.

В примере я использую контравариантность в универсальных интерфейсах, чтобы изменить данные внутри экземпляра универсального класса, работающего с более базовым типом, помещая данные менее базового типа через универсальный интерфейс с этим менее базовым типом.
А если проще, я наливаю воду в бутылку, которая может содержать любой напиток.
Всё по учебнику.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bottle<Drink> BottleForDrink = new Bottle<Drink>();

            IAdd<Water> AddWaterInBottlesForDrink = BottleForDrink;
            AddWaterInBottlesForDrink.Add(new Water());

            IGet<Drink> GetDrinkFromBottleForDrink = BottleForDrink;
            Console.WriteLine(GetDrinkFromBottleForDrink.Get());
        }
    }

    class Drink
    {

    }

    class Water : Drink
    {

    }

    class Milk: Drink
    {

    }

    interface IGet<out T>
    {
        T Get();
    }

    interface IAdd<in T>
    {
        void Add(T Capacity);
    }

    class Bottle<T> : IGet<T>, IAdd<T>
    {
        private T Capacity;

        T IGet<T>.Get()
        {
            return this.Capacity;
        }

        void IAdd<T>.Add(T Capacity)
        {
            this.Capacity = Capacity;
        }
    }
}
```

Но возникла мысль - а зачем мне в данном примере вообще контравариантность и ключевое слово "in".
Я убираю ключевое слово "in" и заставляю свой интерфейс работать с более базовым типом - напиток. Теперь я могу точно также изменить данные внутри экземпляра универсального класса, работающего с более базовым типом, помещая данные менее базового типа через интерфейс, но уже без использования контравариации.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bottle<Drink> BottleForDrink = new Bottle<Drink>();

            IAdd<Drink> AddWaterInBottlesForDrink = BottleForDrink;
            AddWaterInBottlesForDrink.Add(new Water());

            IGet<Drink> GetDrinkFromBottleForDrink = BottleForDrink;
            Console.WriteLine(GetDrinkFromBottleForDrink.Get());
        }
    }

    class Drink
    {

    }

    class Water : Drink
    {

    }

    class Milk: Drink
    {

    }

    interface IGet<out T>
    {
        T Get();
    }

    interface IAdd<T>
    {
        void Add(T Capacity);
    }

    class Bottle<T> : IGet<T>, IAdd<T>
    {
        private T Capacity;

        T IGet<T>.Get()
        {
            return this.Capacity;
        }

        void IAdd<T>.Add(T Capacity)
        {
            this.Capacity = Capacity;
        }
    }
}
```

Я снова налил воду в бутылку, которая может содержать любой напиток.
Обоими способами я могу налить и молоко, так как бутылка может содержать любой напиток, только в первом случае мне понадобится универсальный интерфейс работающий с молоком.

Мне начали писать что универсальный интерфейс с водой (с менее базовым типом) гарантирует что я смогу налить только воду. Хорошо, но чтобы налить что-то кроме воды, как минимум нужно написать код, в котором я наливаю, например, молоко.
Зачем мне писать код про молоко, если мне нужна только вода? По ошибке? Тогда по ошибке я напишу и универсальный интерфейс с молоком и точно так же налью молоко по ошибке, но уже через универсальный интерфейс с контравариантностью.
Объясните, пожалуйста...
Я прошел 18 глав книги и нигде так не застревал.
Я понял принципы по этой теме, думаю что понял...

Comment: «какие конкретные прикладные задачи я не смогу решить без контравариантности»: ответ на это отрицательный: вы в принципе можете решить любую задачу и без продвинутых возможностей наподобие ко-/контравариантности, просто решение будет менее удобным.

Comment: Спасибо. Хорошо. Какие преимущества даёт контравариантность? В указанном мной примере я точно также поместил ссылку на воду в поле экзмепляра двумя разными способами. Результат один. Возможно, пример неудачный. Поможете с более удачным примером?

Comment: Если вам нужно куда-то передать `IAdd<Water>`, а у вас на руках по факту `IAdd<Drink>`, что делать без `in`? Писать обёртку?

Comment: Может быть, этот текст поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516928/10105

Comment: Хм, передать. Допустим у меня есть метод void FillWater(IAdd<Water> AnyVessel) { AnyVessel.Add(new Water()); }, который может заполнять сосуд только водой. Мне нужно наполнить бутылку, подходящую для любого напитка водой. Без in у меня не сработает FillWater(AddWaterInBottlesForDrink) ни через IAdd<Water> потому что Water тип ниже чем Drink, ни через IAdd<Drink> потому что FillWater() принимает только аргумент с типом IAdd<Water>. Но с in сработает через IAdd<Water> потому что теперь тип совместим и точно соответствует типу параметра метода, через IAdd<Drink> сработает потому что...

Comment: ...ссылка на BottleForDrink через аргумент AddWaterInBottlesForDrink с типом IAdd<Drink> в итоге передаётся в параметр с типом IAdd<Water> метода FillWater(). Поправьте если не прав.